# Pandas Filtering by Substring

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with the structure

```
name          code
Big J          323
Big J          323
Big J          323
Big J Online   323
Big J Online   323
Big J Online   323
Code Base      476
Code Base      476
```

Sometimes there are duplicates that contain online. In this situation, I want to keep all of the online versions and remove the offline versions. If there is no online version, I want to keep the offline version.

The result would be

```
Big J Online   323
Big J Online   323
Big J Online   323
Code Base      476
Code Base      476
```

Is there an efficient way to filter this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can filter rows with `Online`, remove it by `replace` and filter out this rows in [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) (solution not working per groups):

```
vals = df.loc[df['name'].str.contains(' Online'), 'name'].str.replace(' Online','')

df = df[~df['name'].isin(vals)]
print (df)
           name  code
3  Big J Online   323
4  Big J Online   323
5  Big J Online   323
6     Code Base   476
7     Code Base   476
```

Same solution per groups:

```
m = df['name'].str.contains('Online')
f = lambda x: x['name'].isin(x['new'])
df = df[~df.assign(new = df.loc[m, 'name'].str.replace(' Online',''))
           .groupby('code', group_keys=False)
           .apply(f)]
print (df)
           name  code
3  Big J Online   323
4  Big J Online   323
5  Big J Online   323
6     Code Base   476
7     Code Base   476
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to solve it is to create a temporary column that checks if 'online' exists in any of the values in `name` per `code`, then filter out those rows:

```
(df.assign(online = df['name'].str.contains('Online'), 
           checker = lambda df: df.groupby('code').online.transform('sum'))
   .loc[lambda df: ~((df.online.eq(0)) & (df.checker.gt(0))), df.columns]
)

          name  code
3  Big J Online   323
4  Big J Online   323
5  Big J Online   323
6     Code Base   476
7     Code Base   476
```

Comment: This solution looks good, but I've accepted the other answer as it's a bit cleaner. Thank you though